# Mylyn Synchronize Local and Remote Repositories

Tags: eclipse, redmine, redmine-plugins, mylyn

I'm currently turning into an avid mylyn user. It really has changed my workflow at work as well as for private projects.

However one thing is bothering me a bit. Especially when working on private project ideas I often stumble upon the following use-case:

1. New idea comes up
2. Create an eclipse project to fool and toy around with said idea
3. Idea slowly turns into project, project gets its git repo

Up to this point, I use mylyn local tasks to manage sub-ideas, tasks and issues
* Now I'd really like to check in these local tasks into a new project on my issue tracker (redmine)

**Is it possible, to synchronize local mylyn tasks with a remote issue tracker repository easily? If yes, how?**

Answer (score 0):

You could use private issues (tasks) in Redmine. You can easily show your Redmine tasks in Mylyn with the [Redmine mylyn connector](http://danmunn.github.io/redmine_mylyn_connector/). I don't know if it's possible to turn local mylyn tasks into Redmine tasks afterwards.